# How to combine variable php in sql query

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to merge variables to determine which table to go to

I use PHP7.0.0

```
$username   = $_GET['username'];
$table      = $_GET['table'];

$sql        = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE username = '$username'";
$result     = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
echo $result['username'];
```

there was no error but the result did not come out

Answer (score 2):

You can define a white list of all possible tables and never merge any unknown input into SQL query. You must also always use prepared statements.

Consider this example:

```
$table = $_GET['table'];

$whitelist = [
    'tableA',
    'tableB'
];

if (!in_array($table, $whitelist, true)) {
    throw new \Exception('This table name is not accepted!');
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM '. $table .' WHERE username=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['username'];
```